# how to push processed data to list and after that send response from express?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, multer

I am trying to resize and upload multiple files using multer. It's working but the problem is when I am sending the data back it is sent before even the data is processed. So I am getting an empty list. I am new to nodejs tried solutions online but couldn't find the right one for me. Can anyone help me solving this problem? How can I push data into the list before sending the response?

the code is Attached below...

```
router.post('/ads/images', upload.array('images',5), async(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.files);

var data = []
await req.files.every(async(file)=>{
    var imageBuffer = await sharp(file.buffer).png().resize({
        width:250,
        fit: sharp.fit.cover,
        position: sharp.strategy.entropy
    }).toBuffer()
    var thumbnailBuffer = await sharp(file.buffer).png().resize({
        width:150,
        height:150,
        fit: sharp.fit.cover,
        position: sharp.strategy.entropy
    }).toBuffer()
    console.log({imageBuffer,thumbnailBuffer});

    data.push({imageBuffer,thumbnailBuffer})
})



console.log(data);

res.send(data)
},(error,req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(400).send({error:error.message})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your every method. Use regular loops in async methods.

Please use a regular for loop instead and apply once only the sharp transforms.

```
for(let file of req.files) {
   (your code here)
}
```

[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Your await call is not doing anything because `every` is not asynchronous. Switch from `every` to `map` then use `Promise.all(..)` to wait for all promises returned by `map` to complete:

```
await Promise.all(req.files.map(async(file) => {
  // ...
}))
```